# How to use NgFor in Angular 2 to indicate an active item on another html object?

Tags: angular, iteration, ngfor

I am using NgFor to iterate through a collection:

```
this.articles = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: “Tile 1“,
        summary: “First Article“
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: “title 2“,
        summary: “Summary 2“
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Title 3”,
        summary: “Summary 3“
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: “Title 4“,
        summary: “Summary 4”
    }
];


<p class="controls">
    &laquo;
    <a (click)="showPrevArticle()">Previous article</a>
    &mdash;
    <a (click)="showNextArticle()">Next article</a>
    &raquo;
</p>
<div class="container">
    <template ngFor let-article [ngForOf]="[ selectedArticle ]" let-i="index">
        <ol class="article-indicators text"  [hidden]="articles.length <= 1">
              <li  *ngFor="let article of articles ; let i = index" [class.active]="selectedBundle === true" (click)="select(article)"><strong>id: </strong>{{i}} </li>
        </ol>

        <div [@articleAnimation]="orientation" class="article">
            <div class="name">
                {{ article.title }}
            </div>
            <div class="avatar">id is: <strong>{{i}}</strong></div>
            <div class="meta">
               {{ article.summary }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

I want a list of items to highlight which article is currently being on display in the "article" div above.

```
<ol class="article-indicators text"  [hidden]="articles.length <= 1">
                  <li  *ngFor="let article of articles ; let i = index" [class.active]="selectedBundle === true" (click)="select(article)"><strong>id: </strong>{{i}} </li>
            </ol>
```

Because the data is not fed through a router, how can I use an equivalent to `[routerLinkActive]="['active']"` to show which article has been pushed to the front?

///Edited

Component code:

This will probably explain better:

At the beginning I set up the animation orientation:

```
type Orientation = ( "prev" | "next" | "none" );
```

My Component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-01',
  animations: [
        trigger(
            "articleAnimation",
            [
                transition(
                    "void => prev", // ---> Entering --->
                    [
                        // Maintain a zIndex of 2 throughout the ENTIRE animation
                        style({
                            left: -100,
                            opacity: 0.0,
                            zIndex: 2
                        }),
                        animate(
                            "200ms ease-in-out",
                            style({
                                left: 0,
                                opacity: 1.0,
                                zIndex: 2
                            })
                        )
                    ]
                ),
                transition(
                    "prev => void", // ---> Leaving --->
                    [
                        animate(
                            "200ms ease-in-out",
                            style({
                                left: 100,
                                opacity: 0.0
                            })
                        )
                    ]
                ),
                transition(
                    "void => next", // <--- Entering <---
                    [
                        // Maintain a zIndex of 2 throughout the ENTIRE
                        // animation (but not after the animation)
                        style({
                            left: 100,
                            opacity: 0.0,
                            zIndex: 2
                        }),
                        animate(
                            "200ms ease-in-out",
                            style({
                                left: 0,
                                opacity: 1.0,
                                zIndex: 2
                            })
                        )
                    ]
                ),
                transition(
                    "next => void", // <--- Leaving <---
                    [
                        animate(
                            "200ms ease-in-out",
                            style({
                                left: -100,
                                opacity: 0.0
                            })
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
    ],
  templateUrl: './article-01.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-01.component.scss']
})
```

Export my class and create my article collection:

```
export class article01Component implements OnInit {
 //indicator states
  selectedArticleId:number;

  isSelected(article): boolean {
       return article.id === this.selectedArticleId;
   }

  public orientation: Orientation;
  public selectedArticle: article;

  private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef;
  private articles: article[];

  constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { 

    this.changeDetectorRef = changeDetectorRef;
    this.orientation = "none";

     // Setup the articles collection.
        this.articles = [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "Article 1 Heading",
                summary: "Summary for article 1"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: "Article 2 Heading",
                summary: "Summary for article 2"            },
            {
                id: 3,
                title: "Article 3 Heading",
                summary: "Summary for article 3"            },
            {
                id: 4,
                title: "Artcile 4 Heading",
                summary: "Summary for article 4"
            }
        ];

          // Randomly(ish) select the initial article to display.
        this.selectedArticle = this.articles[ Math.floor( Math.random() * this.articles.length ) ];

  }
```

Previous button code with implemented method for indicator:

I cycle to the next article in the collection.

```
public showNextArticle() : void {

    // Change the "state" of the animation trigger.
    this.orientation = "next";

    // Force the Template to apply the new animation state before we actually
    // change the rendered element view-model. If we don't force a change-detection,
    // the new [@orientation] state won't be applied prior to the "leave" transition;
    // which means that we won't be leaving from the "expected" state.
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    // Find the currently selected index.
    var index = this.articles.indexOf( this.selectedArticle );
    //THIS IS WRONG:highlight indicator, this is not picking up the correct id
    this.selectedArticleId = index;

    //this.indicatorState(newState)

    // Move the rendered element to the next index - this will cause the current item
    // to enter the ( "next" => "void" ) transition and this new item to enter the
    // ( "void" => "next" ) transition.
    this.selectedArticle = this.articles[ index + 1 ]
        ? this.articles[ index + 1 ]
        : this.articles[ 0 ]
    ;

}
```

My indicators

```
    <ol class="article-indicators text"  [hidden]="articles.length <= 1">
          <li  *ngFor="let article of articles ; let i = index" [class.active]="isSelected(article)"  (click)="select(article)"><strong>id: </strong>{{i}} </li>
    </ol>
```

There seems to be a problem with how the active class is applied as it is doing it on a random basis rather than picking up the current selectedArticle index:

// Find the currently selected index.

```
    var index = this.articles.indexOf( this.selectedArticle );

    this.selectedArticleId = index;


Select the bundle via the indicator (not working):

  public select(selectedArticle){

       selectedArticle.id = this.article.id //property of article does not exist on type 'ArticleComponent'
   }
```

Comment: have a look at my updated answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** (after HGB added the component code)

You already have a `selectedArticle` property, so forget what I said about adding the extra `selectedArticleId`. You should be able to simply change the `[class.active]` code to this:

```
<li  *ngFor="let article of articles ; let i = index" [class.active]="article.id === selectedArticle?.Id" (click)="select(article)"><strong>id: </strong>{{i}} </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Fredrik Lundin said, but I would move the logic to the `Component`

```
export class YourComponent {
   selectedArticleId: int;

   ...

   isSelected(article): boolean {
       return article.id === this.selectedArticleId;
   }

   showNextArticle() {
      ...
      this.selectedArticleId = article.id;
}
```

And html:

```
<li  *ngFor="let article of articles ; let i = index" [class.active]="isSelected(article)" (click)="select(article)"><strong>id: </strong>{{i}} </li>
```

Comment: Should "int" be number? It gives me a "can't find name int" error.

Comment: @HGB yup it should, he copied that mistake from my answer, I updated mine, thanks xD

Comment: @FredrikLundin copy-n-past laziness.

Comment: @FredrikLundin Thanks, but the code is still picking up the index randomly. I have added the full component code, could you check above it is doing what you are trying to show?

Comment: @FredrikLundin that worked! I had to remove the `let i = index` and change `{{i}}` to `{{article.id}}`(it was starting at 0 and applying 0 to all of the article div ones) and also remove the question mark. The only thing that is not working now is the reverse `[class.active]="article.id === selectedArticle.id"  (click)="select(selectedArticle)"` by which you click on the indicator to display the corresponding selectedBundle that matches its id. I have added the code for select to my code.

Comment: another strange thing is when you click on next/prev an entire copy of the <ol> element flashes on the page for split second, is there a reason for this?